# How do I make my Nextcord bot record messages after a command?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, nextcord

I made a bot, and now I want to add a "guess" command where the user tries to guess a number between 1 - 100. The bot will generate a random number and then I want it to record messages after the command has been sent, **and only the messages of that user**.
Here is the code that I've made so far:

```
##GUESS COMMAND
@client.command(name="guess")
async def guess(ctx):
    await ctx.reply("I thought of a number between **1 and 100, You got 5 guesses good luck!**")
    guesses = 0
    num = random.randint(1, 100)
    print(num)
```

So like Me: .guess Bot: I thought of a number between 1 and 100, You got 5 guesses good luck! Me:33 Bot: Incorrect, the number that I guessed is lower/higher (depending on the num var and what the user sent after the command)

I added the guesses variable which adds 1 everytime the user guessed a number to keep track of how many guesses were sent so if it reaches 5 the bot will stop the command and say something like "The number i guessed was ..." and I added print(num) for debigging purposes

I tried adding on_message after the command, but it didn't work out

Answer (score -1):

```
@client.command(name="guess")
async def guess(ctx):
    await ctx.reply("I thought of a number between **1 and 100, You got 5 guesses good luck!**")
    guesses = 0
    num = random.randint(1, 100)
    while True: 
        if guesses>5: # Just in case so it always makes sure there are 5 attempts
            await ctx.reply("No more attempts left") # Tell about no more attempts
            break # Break the loop so it doesn't wait for new messages
        msg = await client.wait_for('message',check=lambda m:m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel and m.content.isdigit()) # Wait for a message in the same channel, by the same user, and make sure the message content is numeral
        guesses+=1 # Another attempt to guess
        num_ = int(msg.content) # The number which the user tried to guess
        if num!=num_:
            await ctx.reply(f"Incorrect! The number that I chose is {'higher' if num_<num else 'lower'}") # tell about it, one lined if else
        else: # if its correct
            await ctx.reply(f"Correct! The number that I chose was {num}") # The message about it
            break # no need to wait for messages again
        if guesses == 5: # no more attempts left
            await ctx.reply(f"No more attempts left my number was {num}!") # Tell about it
            break #no more checking
    print(num)
```

Hey there, thats the answer, I made a lot of  discord bots, so if you got questions, be sure to hit me up ;)

Edit:
Since I was asked to explain it, I did it, again if you have questions, be sure to let me know :)

Comment: Hey thank you so much but after typing a guess a got an error

Comment: Hey, would like to see the issue, probably because I use the disnake library, please be kind and share it :)

Comment: I get an error but i cant fully paste it here but here is the main part - nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: free variable 'msg' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

Comment: Ok fixed it, could you check it again?

Comment: thank you so much! Really appriciate it! Have a nice day <3 <3

Comment: Instead of just pasting a block of code in here that works, it's better to explain the solution and guide OP to it.

Comment: @stijndcl ok done, since you asked it probably meant you needed it, thanks

Comment: Uh no, I didn't need it. This question is very basic and I'm capable of doing that myself. I did read your answer fully. Saying "feel free to ask any questions" isn't good enough for an answer. Other people down the line may bounce into this post, and you probably won't be replying to comments here in 3 years. Also, by just giving OP the solution they aren't learning anything and will be stuck on similar situations. "Hey here this is the answer" doesn't teach OP - or other people reading to this - anything. There's a big difference between understanding someone's code and doing it yourself.

Comment: You'll encounter similar comments on every code-only-answer on SO. That's just how this site works.